# Converting XML to Html using Xsl stylessheet

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have come across a bottleneck here,

I have an XML file which contains following structure.

```
 <content>
    <procedure>
    <commonInfo>
    <title>           <inlineSignificantData significantParaDataType="psd51">TASK 72-31-00-030-001</inlineSignificantData> LP Compressor (LPC) Fan Module - Disassemble</title>
    <para/>
    <commonInfoDescrPara>
    <title>General</title>
    <para>This TASK gives the procedure to disassemble the LP Compressor (Fan) Module.</para>
    <para>Fig/item numbers in parentheses in the procedure agree with those used in the IPC. Only the primary Fig/item numbers are used. For the service bulletin alpha variants refer to the IPC.</para>
    <para>Apply the approved penetrating oils before the removal of threaded parts and parts having an interference fit. Let the parts soak before removal. For the approved penetrating oils and procedures, refer to the SPM <dmRef><dmRefIdent><dmCode assyCode="00" disassyCode="00" disassyCodeVariant="A" infoCode="240" infoCodeVariant="A" itemLocationCode="D" modelIdentCode="IHIX1" subSubSystemCode="4" subSystemCode="6" systemCode="70" systemDiffCode="00"/></dmRefIdent></dmRef>.</para>
    <para>Refer to <internalRef internalRefId="fig-0001" internalRefTargetType="figure"/> for a sectional view of a LP compressor (fan) module.</para>
    </commonInfoDescrPara>
</commonInfo>
<preliminaryRqmts>
<reqCondGroup>
<noConds/></reqCondGroup>
<reqSupportEquips><supportEquipDescrGroup><supportEquipDescr id="seq-0001"><name>Removal puller</name><identNumber><manufacturerCode>VENDOR1</manufacturerCode><partAndSerialNumber><partNumber>SE 201</partNumber></partAndSerialNumber></identNumber><reqQuantity>1</reqQuantity>
</supportEquipDescr>
</preliminaryRqmts>
</procedure>
  </content>
```

and I have XSL file which converts this to Html

<

```
xsl:template match="content">
    <ol class="ata-list">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="description|procedure"/>
    </ol>-->
  </xsl:template>
```

what I would like to do here is, I do not want to print the following xml inside the `<ol> </ol>` tags.

```
<commonInfo>
<title>           <inlineSignificantData significantParaDataType="psd51">TASK 72-31-00-030-001</inlineSignificantData> LP Compressor (LPC) Fan Module - Disassemble</title>
</commonInfo>
```

Instead, I would like to print details above the  tags

```
<dev>
apply template <commonInfo>
<dev>

<ol class="ata-list">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="procedure"/> with out the common tags
    </ol>-->
```

how do I achive this ? pelase help

Comment: Couldn't you have made the effort to indent your XML nicely for readability?

Answer (score 0):

Try using modes:

```
<xsl:template match="content">
    <dev>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="procedure/commonInfo" mode="ci"/>
    </dev>
    <ol class="ata-list">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="description|procedure" mode="dp"/>
    </ol>
  </xsl:template>
```

and then have different template rules for the two processing modes (add a `mode="x"` attribute to the relevant `xsl:template` and `xsl:apply-templates` elements).